# Trying to find sets of nodes that disconnects graph, with networkx in python

Tags: python, graph, networkx

So i'm trying to solve: "Find a graph algorithm that will identify set(s) of nodes that, if removed, causes the graph to shatter into at least two connected components. Use it to identify such set(s) for your network."

I found this function here: https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.connectivity.kcutsets.all_node_cuts.html which looks exactly like what i'm looking for.

So i try to run this:

`pg_all_node_cuts = len(nx.all_node_cuts(pg))`

Problem is, this takes forever to run. I haven't been able to finish running this, after running for maybe 6 hours.

So im wondering, does anyone have a alternative python library that is faster or something else in networkx that helps my problem?, or am I misunderstanding what I should find?

Thanks

Comment: `flow_func` is the third argument. The second argument is the ineteger `k`. Are you sure you copied your code here correctly?

Comment: Besides that `all_node_cuts` is a generator which has no `len` so actually this code would fail immediately.

Comment: Yes my mistake, i erased the second argument. Have corrected the function call in the post now. and my mistake, in the example used in the documentation of the function, the generator call is wrapped into a list before using len. Now i am calling this correctly but it is still taking a very, very long time. So i ask, is there any other python library that does what im trying to do, or am i simply misunderstanding this? The code i run can be seen in my answer below. The for loop has only printed out one set so far, and has been running for an hour.

Comment: Are you supposed to find all such sets? Do they have to be minimal? The algorithm that networkx is using has very high time complexity according to the original paper. Other more recent algorithms are in papers behind paywalls.

Comment: Yes it has been running for about 24 hours now and hasn't finished. I am starting to think that I am only supposed to find every node that disconnects the graph into two connected components. But the ambiguity is that in the description of the problem it says, "set(s)". I am not sure to be honest. It doesn't state anywhere that they have to be minimal, what difference does that make ?

Answer (score 0):

```
pg_all_node_cuts = nx.all_node_cuts(pg)
for b in pg_all_node_cuts:
  print(b)
```

Comment: Please provide some explanation to it so other user can easily understand it

Comment: This answer is related to my comment in my original post above. I couldn't include this code separated by newlines in the answer. If you read the first paragraph in my original post where i describe what i am asked to find, i understand that this function does what is asked for. But this takes forever to run, It's been running for about 24 hours and still hasn't finished. So I was asking if anyone knows of any other python library or algorithm that does what I need to do that is not so computationally expensive. Or even, according to the description of the problem if i am misunderstanding this